# Ionic left side menu with hamburger

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, material-design

How can I create Ionic left side menu with hamburger button?

Something similar to this:

[image]

Comment: I don't know where you can find a tutorial, but you want to looks for "sliding panel" or "sliding window" with CSS transition (or animation).

Comment: one of the 3 templates provides for ionic has a side menu, download it and check how they did it

Answer (score 3):

Well, since it is still relevant in search engines. As I ended up here too.
Here is a way to go about this:

This code below, inserts the side menu options. 
src/app/app.html

```js
<ion-menu [content]="mySideMeu">
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title>
        Menu Bar
      </ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

  <ion-content>

    <ion-list>
        <button ion-item menuClose (click)="onOpenPage(settingsPage)"><ion-icon name="settings" item-left></ion-icon> Settings</button>
        <button ion-item menuClose (click)="onOpenPage(otherPage)"><ion-icon name="car" item-left></ion-icon> Other Page</button>
    </ion-list>

  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

<ion-nav #mySideMeu [root]="homePage"></ion-nav>
```

Now that you have created the side menu, you are ready to just slide it off of the side of the screen, even though you can't see that is there.

It's now time to add the 'hamburger' icon on the screens that you want it to appear.
Keep in mind that you may not want it to appear in all the pages.
So, for that side menu to slide out with a touch (click) you add the following code below to every screen(page) you want it to appear.

```js
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    
    <ion-buttons start>
      <button ion-button menuToggle>
        <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
    
    <ion-title>Profile</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

The key here to this side menu to work is the directive "menuToggle" to open the side menu on different page views/screens and the directive "menuClose" to close the side menu after clicked.

Cheers.